# Ionic 4 Firebase IOS Application

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

How to keep a user logged in using firebase, even when the application closes? I have heard local device storage is a no-go.

Comment: are you using ionic native firebase? or something like [this](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b74e54f80aca74669894413/ionic-4-and-angular-6-tutorial-firebase-realtime-crud-mobile-app)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ionic native firebase plugin and instead using something like in this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b74e54f80aca74669894413/ionic-4-and-angular-6-tutorial-firebase-realtime-crud-mobile-app) you can use this code below

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) for more details